# Превратить индексированный массив в группированный ассоциативный

Tags: php, алгоритм

Собственно, задачка элементарная, но надоело велосипедить. Более чем уверен, что есть умное решение:

```
$arr = array(
[0]=>array(
'group'=>'abc',
'name'=>'name1'
),
[0]=>array(
'group'=>'abc',
'name'=>'name3'
),
[0]=>array(
'group'=>'def',
'name'=>'name4'
),
[0]=>array(
'group'=>'abc',
'name'=>'name2'
),
[0]=>array(
'group'=>'def',
'name'=>'name5'
),
);
```

должно превратиться в

```
array(
'abc'=>array(
'name1','name2','name3'),
'def'=>array('name4','name5')
)
```

Постоянно решаю через сортировку (`usort`) по группе, потом

```
$finalList = array();
$tmpQueue = array();
$previous = '';
foreach($arr as $elem){
    $tmpQueue[] = $elem['name'];
    if($elem['group']!=$previous){
        if($previous!=''){
            $finalList[$previous] = $tmpQueue;
            $tmpQueue = array();
        }
        $previous = $elem['group'];
    }
}
if(!empty($tmpQueue)){
    $finalList[$previous] = $tmpQueue;
}
```

Но вы этого не видели. :)

Comment: хм, а зачем там эти все $previos и тд ? чего бы просто не пройти по этому массиву и не запушить в результирующий ?

Comment: как-то так http://ideone.com/gNo5hF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну я тогда тоже свой коммент ответом сделаю.

```
$fin=array();
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    $fin[$el['group']][]=$el['name'];
}
```

Comment: Ага. В какой-то момент оно было нужно для промежуточных действий, а потом я его юзал по старой памяти, считая, что без него никак.

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array();
array_walk
(
    $arr,
    function( $item )
    {
        global $data;
        $data[$item['group']][] = $item['name'];
    }
);
```

Можно и поизящней, без `global`, но лень :)

Comment: подсказка из зала - [use](http://ideone.com/Zh54mo)

Comment: да сам по себе array_walk тут избыточен, это так - мало ли что ещё захочется  :)